# Sql creation format

Tags: mysql, sql

How would one format the following sql file in a way that would work and keep the current values;

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE "login" (
"IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 "username" varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 "pass" varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("IdUser")
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE "photos" (
"IdPhoto" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
"title" varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
"IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("IdPhoto")
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

I get the following error when I try to create it from my mac terminal

> "'ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '"login" (
>         "IdUser" int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>         "username" varchar(45) C' at line 1
>       "

Comment: try to remove quotes

Comment: MySQL uses backticks `\`` to escape names, not double-quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this.  **[Fiddler Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b012)**

```
CREATE TABLE login (
IdUser int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 username varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 pass varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IdUser)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE photos (
IdPhoto int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
IdUser int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IdPhoto)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE login (//"login" is incorrect syntex
IdUser int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, // Dont give "" to Column name 
 username varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
 pass varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IdUser)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

CREATE TABLE photos (//"photos" is incorrect syntex
IdPhoto int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
title varchar(100) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
IdUser int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (IdPhoto)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFA
```